# Hide or edit the "You cannot add another 'xxx' to your cart" error message in WooCommerce 4.5+

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Via the product settings I enabled "sold individually: enable this to only allow one item to be bought in a single order"

While adding the same product to cart, there appears an error message because I enabled this setting. The error message is **"You cannot add another 'xxx' to your cart"**. I don't want the same product added to the cart, so this works fine and
good.

My question:

How to hide the error message **"You cannot add another 'xxx' to your cart"**.

If I use the CSS code

```css
.woocommerce-error {
    display: none;
}
```

Then the error password or email when we log in is hidden too, I don't want to hide another error message.

Is it possible to achieve only for this error to be hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the message, you can use since **WooCommerce 4.5.0** the `woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message` filter hook.

```php
/**
 * Filters message about more than 1 product being added to cart.
 *
 * @since 4.5.0
 * @param string     $message Message.
 * @param WC_Product $product_data Product data.
 */
function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message( $message, $product_data ) {
    // New text
    $message = __( 'My new message', 'woocommerce' );

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message', 10, 2 );
```

To hide the message completely, just replace

```php
// New text
$message = __( 'My new message', 'woocommerce' );
```

With

```php
// New text
$message = '';
```

However, the "problem" with the above solution is that the message is now hidden, but the `woocommerce-error` (red box) and `view-cart` button is still displayed.

---

So while using the filter hook, you can add some extra jQuery to hide the `woocommerce-error`

**Note:** although the below works, it is never a good idea to hide error messages. These are there for a reason, to make a customer aware of something. Hence, this solution is a bit 'tricky'.

But to answer your question, you can use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message( $message, $product_data ) {    
    $message = '<div class="hide-this-error-message"></div>';
    
    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_cannot_add_another_message', 10, 2 );

function action_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $( '.hide-this-error-message' ).closest( 'ul.woocommerce-error' ).hide();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer' );
```

Comment: Regarding your note - if on my site, I don't think it's a problem for customers, because if the product is already in the cart, the "add to cart" button changes to "Click View cart"